# Can I edit rows of JqGrid which is bound to dynamic data

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqGrid which I am binding dynamically. I'm using jqgrid version 5.2

I have to implement **add/edit/delete** on the dynamic data. I have set add, edit delete as true in navgrid option

```
$("#grdRawData").jqGrid({
    url: vURLJQ,
    datatype: 'local',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: data.d.IDresult,
    mtype: 'Get',
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    styleUI: "Bootstrap",
    guiStyle: "bootstrap",


    colNames: BuildColumnNames(col),

    colModel: BuildColumnModel(col),

    localReader: {
        root: data.d.IDresult,
        page: 1,
        total: 1500,
        records: data.d.IDresult.length
        // repeatitems: false
        //Id: "0"
    },
    pager: jQuery('#grdRawDataPager'),
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 50, 100, 150, 200],
    //sortname: 'Urgency',
    //sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    overlay: 0,

    //pgbuttons: true,
    //pginput: false,
    emptyrecords: 'No records',
    loadComplete: function() {
        var gridData = $("#grdRawData").jqGrid('getRowData');
    }
}).navGrid('#grdRawDataPager', {
    edit: true,
    add: true,
    del: true,
    search: true,
    searchtext: "Find"
});
```

But when I edit a record, the edit dialog appears but empty. 
Can anyone help me here, please? I'm not able to add/edit/delete the dynamic data-bound to my jqGrid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you mean under dynamic data-bound to jqGrid? Your datatype is local, so you should edit the record fine. Be a sure you have set uniquie row id and define it so that jqGrid understand it. Can you please post a demo data which come top the grid?

Comment: Thanks for the response Tony. By dynamic data bound to jqGrid, I mean I am binding the colnames and colmodel dynamically, as data may vary based on some selection on the UI. Demo data is shown below:                                          Active: True , Billable: False,  Cart: ,Category: a8c1b97a7cb5a8006216b82ff00bea51 , Cart_Value: , Category: Employee Management ,Sys_ID: 007c1fe90f975e008a581b2be1050e16 ,Class: sc_cat_item , Created: 5/10/2016  10:58:26 AM                                                         Sorry for the format. But was not sure how to type tabular data.

Comment: Also, I have added a key column which is hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the colModel is not published, the only reason that there are no fields in the edit form is that you do not set the **editable** option true in colModel. Try with this colModel:

```
$("#grdRawData").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        {name: 'Active', editable: true},
        {name: 'Billable', editable: true},
        {name: 'Cart', editable: true},
        {name : 'Category', editable: true },
        {name : 'Cart_Value', editable: true}, 
        {name: 'Category', editable: true},
        {name: 'Sys_ID', key : true, editable: true},
        {name : 'Class', editable: true},
        {name : 'Created', editable: true}
    ],
...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tony. While creating the colModel dynamically, I missed this attribute. Thanks a lot !!! However, I'm facing another problem. The dynamic data can have max column count upto 25. And when I load large number of columns, my grid header and data are misaligned.

Comment: @aaru11 Thanks. The only way to look into this is to have working example. Usually this is caused from the data that come into the grid or some problem with jsonReader/xmplReader definition. I note again, that the only way to look into this is a working example.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. I am not able to post my code here.

Comment: One possible resolution is to use by example [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)  or similar